# date from database to html datepicker showing 01/01/1970

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datepicker

I want to auto get auto date value from database to html form on datepicker, I tried this one but getting 01/01/1970 instead of that date stored in database.

```
<input name="last_date" type="date" value="<?php echo strftime('%Y-%m-%d', strtotime($query[lastdate]->startdate)); ?>" />
```

while when I try , `<? echo $query['lastdate']; ?>` it showing correct date from database

Comment: What "correct date" does it actually show? do a  var_dump of `$query['lastdate']`

Comment: Do a var_dump of `$query[lastdate]->startdate` and let us know what value is in there.

Comment: @MarkBaker is shows '2015-11-26 00:00:00' as a correct date ! can you please tell how to use that var_dump

Comment: @JonathanKuhn how to do var_dump :?

Comment: If `var_dump($query['lastdate']);` shows `'2015-11-26 00:00:00'` then what is `$query[lastdate]->startdate`?

Comment: `'2015-11-26 00:00:00'` is not  valid ISO string format. `new Date('2015-11-26 00:00:00')` will return invalid date in some browsers

Comment: `$query[lastdate]->startdate` showing `01/01/1970` on datepicker

Comment: Like mark is saying, if `$query[lastdate]` is the date, what are you trying to do with the `->startdate` part? Is `$query[lastdate]` an object? Because that is what your code is trying to use.

Comment: I want to auto pick that value of $query[lastdate] from database to datepicker in html form, which I want to use for update database feature